# Groovy syntax - how does doFirst work in Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

When declaring a task in gradle it looks like I can write:

```
task myTask {
 doFirst {
   //do something
 }
}
```

I'm wondering how the interpreter knows to run `doFirst` on the task object?

It would make more sense to me if we had:

```
it.doFirst {
 //do something
}
```

Because then it would be obvious that doFirst was being called on `it`, which must be the task object itself being passed into the closure.
How does groovy's syntax allow for my first snippet above to work?

I'm new to groovy but I haven't seen anything in the docs in regards to this

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_delegation_strategy

Comment: Personally I do NOT want to see stuff like `it.doLast{}` in my DSL